# Update Jira Select List Custom Field using Rest API and CURL

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api

Good Day All,
I've been looking around the past few days trying to find the right syntax to build my request. Many articles on SO and even Atlassians Docs, but I havn't found anything that would fit my needs.
I have a custom field in Jira which is a Select List (Multi select field). I would like to set the value of this with a curl command. Here is what I am currently trying

```
curl -D- -u *:* -X PUT --data "{\"customfield_10614\": [ { \"id\": \"13500\" }, { \"id\": \"13400\" } ] }" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira.*.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/MMB-3039
```

I've tried many variations of this same command looking for the right syntax.

Other curl requets work for me such as

```
curl http://jira.*.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/EI-1?fields=customfield_10613
```

and

```
curl -D- -u *:* -X POST -d "{\"body\": \"Comment added when resolving issue\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira.*.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/EI-3324/comment
```

But i am currently getting "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" as a response to my request to update the Select List.(not sure if it should be a post or put)

Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: It's not a permissions issue?

Comment: I don't think its a permission issue, as I am able to login manually and make this edit. I am also able to leave comments using REST

Answer (score 2):

Solved. After trying some different syntaxes I came across the correct format.

```
curl -D- -u *:* -X PUT --data "{\"fields\" : {\"customfield_10614\": [{ \"value\": \"TST1\" }, { \"value\": \"TST2\" }]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira.*.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/MMB-1000
```

1. I needed a PUT instead of POST
2. The url should not have the /jira directory after the port
3. Json --data was not in correct format